# Reference a workbook with a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables, reference

I try to save and then open the same workbook but I had 'subscript out of range' error. I couldn't find any solution that open and set a variable that workbook with a variable.

I declire new variables like FN but cannot solve. How can I fix it?

```
WeekNum = Format(Date, "ww")
path1 = "W_"
path2 = "Haftalik_Sonuclar.xlsm"
FN = path1 & WeekNum & path2
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ("Z:\07_SUPPLY_CHAIN\07-G B\PG\W_" & WeekNum & "Haftalik_Sonuclar.xlsm")
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Workbooks(FN).Open
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks(Filename)
```

'subscript out of range'

Comment: Is there a reason you want to Close and open the same workbook? Please make a short example, because maybe there might be another solution.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the path (`Z:\07_SUPPLY_CHAIN\07-G B\PG\`) in `FN`

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) of Workbooks.Open method:

```
expression.Open FileName
```

So, use

```vb
workbooks.open "Z:\07_SUPPLY_CHAIN\07-G B\PG\W_" & WeekNum & "Haftalik_Sonuclar.xlsm"
```

Not

```
Workbooks(FN).Open
```